# Polymer starter-kit 2 Javascript scope

Tags: javascript, html, scope, polymer-starter-kit

In my-app.html

```
...

<paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu"  onclick="this.$._joesDrawerToggle()"></paper-icon-button>

...

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-app',

    ...

    _showPage404: function() {
      this.page = 'view404';
    },


    _joesDrawerToggle: function () {

      if (this.$.drawer.opened) {
        this.$.drawer.close();
      }else{
        this.$.drawer.open();
      }

    }
  });
</script>
```

When editing my-app.html, WebStorm auto-complete **finds** this.$._j **as** this.$._joesDrawerToggle()

However, when i click the button, Chrome Dev Tools says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.$._joesDrawerToggle is not a function
    at HTMLElement.onclick ((index):1)
onclick @ (index):1
```

It seems index.html needs to know about _joesDrawerToggle(). I am not sure why.

How can i make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu"  onclick="this.$._joesDrawerToggle()"></paper-icon-button>
```

to

```
<paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu"  on-tap="_joesDrawerToggle"></paper-icon-button>`
```

Comment: I changed `on-click` in to `on-tap` now it should work

Comment: Good follow up.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
<paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu"  on-tap="_joesDrawerToggle"></paper-icon-button>
```

I found the following link, "[Annotated event listener setup](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners)". It has a "Tip" that says,

> Tip: Use on-tap rather than on-click for an event that fires consistently across both touch (mobile) and click (desktop) devices. See gesture events for a complete list of reliable, cross-platform events.